# Having trouble accessing a remote repository in Xcode 12.3

Tags: xcode, authentication, github, repository

Every time I try to pull from the remote repository my friend and I are working on, I get an error saying that it could not be accessed and to check if a valid repository exists at the specified location and that the correct credentials have been supplied. The problem is that I am already added as a member of the project (with the permission to write) and I have also cloned the repository into my computer.

Any ideas as to how I should go about this?

here is a screenshot of the error message I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3UZG.png)

Comment: can you show where you have added the remote and how

Comment: having a similar problem with one of my current projects, I tried removing my GitHub account in Xcode preferences and re-adding, then regenerating my access token but to no avail, in the end I just opened a terminal in the project folder and used bash commands, trouble is now Xcode seems to keep 'forgetting' my account, if I discover anything more permanent I'll post...